# printing information of two files according specific field

Tags: awk

I have two files. I need to print information like the example, when the first field exist and is equal, in two files.

```
file 1
20;"aaaaaa";99292929
24;"fsfdfa";42933294
30;"fsdsff";23832299
38;"fjsdjl";62673777

file 2
13;"fsdffsdfs";2272777
20;"ffuiiii";23728877
30;"wdwfsdh";8882817
40;"sfjslll";82371111

expect result:
file1;20;"aaaaaa";99292929;file2;20;"ffuiiii";23728877
file1,30;"fsdsff";23832299;file2;30;"wdwfsdh";8882817
```

I tried with:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1;next} $1 in a' file2 file1 > newfile
```

logical it's ok, but I can't show fields that I want.

Comment: `join -t';' file1 file2` handles the join perfectly without any code (as long as the files are sorted), but your output format can't be obtained with that tool alone and at this point you might as well perform the join with `awk` I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` will help:

```
awk -F ';' 'NR==FNR{rec[$1]=FILENAME FS $0}
            NR>FNR{
              if($1 in rec){
              print rec[$1] FS FILENAME FS $0
              }
            }' file{1..2}
```

should do.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
{ $0 = FILENAME FS $0 }
NR==FNR { a[$2] = $0; next }
$2 in a { print a[$2], $0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
file1;20;"aaaaaa";99292929;file2;20;"ffuiiii";23728877
file1;30;"fsdsff";23832299;file2;30;"wdwfsdh";8882817
```